# insert select statement with changes to fields and logic thinking

Tags: php, mysql, date, logic

I'm working on some php code having to do with creating recurring invoices.  I need some help thinking through the logic.  I think ultimately I will end up with a type of Insert/Select statement.  The php code that is ultimately generated here will run in a nightly cron.

First, let me show you some of my table items for a frame of reference and explain a bit about what they do.  The table is called Invoice and there are other tables associated with it, but I think if I can nail now this one table's logic, I can apply it to the others.

ID = This is the primary key that auto increments and also happens to be the invoice number.

recurring = This is whether the invoice is one time or recurring.  O=One time, M=Monthly etc

recurred = This will be set to N on insert and is the logic I'm using to see if the next recurring invoice that will be created in the table should be based off this invoice or not.  When a new recurring invoice is inserted into the table, this will be changed to Y so its not processed again by the cron job.

date = This is the date that the invoice was inserted/created.  For example, if date the invoice was created is the 15th of this month, the next invoice created will be the 15th of next month.  Essentially M represents monthly.  However, I haven't figured out yet what to do about a created date of the 31st but the next month only has 30 days, could use some help here.

So here is my logic.  First, I run a query to find all rows that are not O and recurred = N.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE recurring != 'O' and recurred
```

= 'N'") or die(mysql_error());

Next, I work on each kind of recurring M for monthly, Q for quarterly, etc..

```
if recurring = M
 if todays date day = 'date' day
  copy line item into a new row with the following changes: new ID, todays date, and mark the recurred to N for the new insert (will mark the old one Y)
```

Obviously that is not actual code, just what I'm thinking about.

So my questions are 1.) How to create a insert select statement to deal with changed variables and 2.) how to deal with dates where if the invoice was created on the 31st of one month and the next month only has 30 days (or 28).

Answer (score 1):

take only rows that need to be re-inserted:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date`, NOW()) as diff FROM invoice WHERE recuring != 'O' 
AND recured = 'N' AND diff >= 30;
```

iterate through that list and use a new date for each row by calculating it with:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($oldDate+" +1 month"));
```

This should solve your 30th day of month problem.

Now insert newly created data.

Also, good advice to use enum for recuring field, and boolean for recured.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  Not sure what enum vs boolean means.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Avetis, I will have to make computations for Monthly(M) Quarterly(Q) semiannual(S) Annual(A).  Are you recommending I run this query for each type since you added diff>= 30?  Or should I run it once and get everything and sort it out with if statements?

Comment: Regarding the enum and boolean, you were using letters O, Y, N, M as "string" to identify things, which is bad for database, you should change the types according to your logic, so if you need a yes/no typo of field it should be boolean (true/false) if you are having several options like monthly/quarterlu/daily then type of field should be enum where you can have the exact names enum(daily, monthly .e.g.) and it will all work more efficiently.

Comment: Regarding the different date ranges for different types, you can of course make several queries for each type, I assume there is not too many. Or you can make a better WHERE statement like WHERE (recuring = 'M' AND diff >= 30) || (recuring = 'Y' AND diff >= 365) e.g. and in the PHP code instead of +1 month use +1 year +1 day, according to recuring field (by using if's) so in that case you will make just one query to select, one query to insert, and a foreach iteration over only updatable rows in PHP. SOunds good?

Answer (score 0):

I have made somewhat similar application. In my case I had 2 tables: actual invoices and recurring invoices. Recurring table had one field called NextDate - the date when next invoice should be created. One time invoice is added directly into invoices table, otherwise the cron job scans the recurring table and checks for a NextDate value. If it is in past then new invoice is generated into invoices table and NextDate is updated (normally incremented by month).

In my case incrementing by month changes month value only by 1. For example in MySQL

```
DATE_ADD('2008-01-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  --> 2008-02-29
```

Comment: I like the idea of a nextdate field, might use that in conjunction with Avetis's suggestion.

Comment: What happens when you go in reverse?  Start with an invoice dated 1-31-2013.  Next invoice created is 2-28-2013.  What will the next one look like?  Will it be 3-31-2013?

Comment: I think the safe bet would be to use the original date (1-31-2013) and do INTERVAL 1, INTERVAL 2 etc.

Comment: original date=the date that is entered when creating invoice. After 2 months you do then DATE_ADD('2008-01-31', INTERVAL 2 MONTHS)